Help! Get Column Names (not internal) in a Track SharePoint Column Changes Flow
I'm building a flow to track column changes in SharePoint, following this video.
It all works great, except I'd like the notification email to show the column display names instead of the internal column names.
I was told to map new column names, but I'm unsure how.
Below is my Track Field list and Keys.
Any help would be appreciated.

